# Camera not working in landscape mode only project?

Tags: objective-c, camera, landscape

I have developed landscape mode only project and UIcamera picture controller using take photo but it crashed when camera launched and it will show this reason: Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.

```
 if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage,nil];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;


        [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
//        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:NO completion:^{
//                [imagePicker setShowsCameraControls:YES];
//            }];

        }else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"No camera available" message: @"Failed to take image" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this friends:

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No camera available" message:@"Failed to take image" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```